# Optimizing quicksort

Tags: c++, performance, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

I created simple quicksort algorithm using iterators. I'm happy with implementation but not with its speed. Profiler tells me that the slowest operation here is `std::iter_swap`. I don't really know how to improve this code. Note that I am not asking for different kind of quicksort algorithm but about improving this one.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare = std::less_equal<>>
void Sort::QuickSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare = Compare())
{
    if (std::distance(first, last) <= 1) return;
    RandomIt pivot = Partition(first, last, compare);
    QuickSort(first, pivot, compare);
    QuickSort(std::next(pivot, 1), last, compare);
}

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
RandomIt Sort::Partition(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    RandomIt pivot = MedianOf3(first, last, compare);
    RandomIt i = first;
    for (RandomIt j = first; j != pivot; ++j)
        if (compare(*j, *pivot)) {
            std::iter_swap(i, j);
            ++i;
        }
    std::iter_swap(i, pivot);
    return i;
}

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
RandomIt Sort::MedianOf3(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
{
    auto collectionSize = std::distance(first, last);
    RandomIt middle = std::next(first, collectionSize / 2);
    RandomIt targetPivot = std::prev(last, 1);
    if (compare(*middle, *first))
        std::iter_swap(middle, first);
    if (compare(*targetPivot, *first))
        std::iter_swap(targetPivot, first);
    if (compare(*middle, *targetPivot))
        std::iter_swap(middle, targetPivot);
    return targetPivot;
}
```

For testing I used vectors of 100 000 random elements. This code average sorting time is about 1626 ms on my machine and `std::sort` on the same set of data performs 10 times better, around 163 ms. I know that `std::sort` uses introsort but still quicksort shouldn't be 10 times slower.

Comment: You might get better reviews if you show the test program (if you don't want that part reviewed, just say so) and the necessary headers (at least `<iterator>`; perhaps others?).

Comment: I'd say that your performance problem is that `std::iter_swap()` is called too many times.  Try moving `i` forwards from `first` while `*i` is less than `*pivot` and `j` backwards from `last` while `*pivot` is less than `*j`, then, when `*j` < `*pivot` < `*i`, perform the swap.  Repeat until `i`==`j`.

Comment: I'll try it, it will definitely improve performance. I will need some time for it, iterators have some edge cases in Hoare's scheme that I need to think about. Another minor question, is it ok to write something like `std::prev(last, 1)` or `last - 1` is better?

Comment: Personally, I find `last - 1` easier to read and should be defined for all `RandomIterator` types.  I only use `std::prev()` when I really need a function to pass around.  There could be something I missed, so don't just accept my say-so on that!

Answer (score 3):

To get this code to compile I had to add the `Sort` namespace definition:

```
namespace Sort
{
    template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare = std::less_equal<>>
    void QuickSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare = Compare());

    template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
    RandomIt Partition(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare);

    template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
    RandomIt MedianOf3(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare);
}
```

And I had to remove the default argument from the redeclaration of `Sort::QuickSort`:

```
template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare = std::less_equal<>>
void Sort::QuickSort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare compare)
```

Review requests should have issues like that already accounted for.

---

The performance of the `Partition()` function can be improved by doing fewer swaps.  The current loop swaps when `*j` < `*pivot`, without considering whether `*i` is less or greater than `*pivot`.  Instead, we can use two iterators, and advance them towards each other, swapping only when the ascending iterator points to an item greater than pivot *and* the descending iterator points to one smaller than pivot.  The tricky bit is to avoid the iterators passing each other without terminating.